# Where to set kernels buffer/cache size

Tags: linux, kernel, ram

I have 16GB of RAM with Debian 9 in my notebook but almost all of it is unused by the kernel. It uses only 1GB for buffer/cache.

Where can I tell the kernel to use more of the free RAM for caching?
My FS is Ext4.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you deduce that something more should be cache what isn't already cached by kernel? Kernel doesn't reclaim cached pages if there is unused memory to be utilized.

Comment: The kernel uses 1GB for cache. 14GB is unused and I have 2,5TB of disk. So think it should use a lot more of the free memory to buffer a bit more of the disk.

Comment: The kernel can only cache data that has been accessed. Have you actually read more than 1GB of data from the disk since the last boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel only caches data that has been accessed.  If you have not read more than 1GB of data from the disk since the last boot, then it will not have more than 1GB cached.